# Right method to install laravel on my local computer

Tags: laravel

I am new for laravel. I need to install laravel in my local computer. 
i found many tutorial for that but there are showing different different method to install them.

1. composer global require "laravel/installer"
2. composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer-dist

in above two method which one is best method to install and is it any differentiate between them?

Any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) has clear directions on installing Laravel. If you are not using Homestead, then you must install:

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension

The two commands will achieve the same means to an ends, the first installs the laravel installer and the second does one off applications:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

I prefer the first method, having the Laravel installer globally available is convenient, as you only need to run `laravel new projectName` there after. Having composer's `bin` directory in your `$PATH` is required with this method:

```
macOS: $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin

GNU / Linux Distributions: $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first you install wampserver or xamp or....
2. after installation, install composer https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
3. [image]
4. choose php version
   [image]
   5 .next->next->install
5. then restart your server.
6. open cmd comment
7. install laravel global (cmd->)
   C:\Users\name> composer global require "laravel/installer"
   after installation
   9 you select your project folder using cmd example (cd c:\wamp\www\myproject)
8. cmd comment laravel new  
   exmaple(C:\wamp64\www\myproject>laravel new testapp)
9. to run your project C:\wamp64\www\myproject\testapp>php artisan serve.
10. open your browser search. http://localhost:8080)

more information about to install laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Details about step by step cmd comments
1. Check composer version ----> C:\Users\name>composer -v
2. Install laravel ----> C:\Users\name> composer global require "laravel/installer"
3. Get new laravel app ---> C:\Users\name\www\wamp\projectfolder>laravel new blog or laravel new 
4. choose laravel app version composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"
to run rou laravel app >C:\Users\name\www\wamp\projectfolder/ php artisan serve